# Mine antipersonnel ou mine antipersonnelle ?

Tags: orthographe, accord

Quelle est l'orthographe correcte et comment la justifier ?

Comment: Cette mine antipersonnel(le) me semble injustifiable ;-)

Comment: [Aussi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1463).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce n'est pas très intuitif au premier coup d'oreille, mais l'orthographe correcte est *antipersonnel*, et ce mot est un adjectif invariable en genre où *personnel* **est un nom**, comme dans *antichar*. Ces deux adjectifs s'accordent toutefois normalement en nombre.

Comment: N'est-ce pas parce c'est utilisé dans le sens "le personnel qui travaille ici"?

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'il s'accorde « normalement » en nombre (ou alors donne un exemple). Je vois bien comment on peut dire « un missile antichars, anti-sous-marins ou anti-aériens » (bien que *aérien* en tant que nom est assez rare), mais ce n'est pas l'écriture intuitive. C'est vrai qu'il se peut qu'un missile soit assez efficace pour en détruire plusieurs. Mais plus abstraitement on peut dire « des missiles antichar, anti-sous-marin ou anti-aérien » c'est un choix sémantique indépendant du nombre… de missiles.

Comment: Mon Petit Robert est très clair sur la variabilité de l'adjectif *antichar*, et traite *antipersonnel* pour une raison que je ne m'explique pas (p-ê parce que *personnel* est [indénombrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)) comme invariable, mais aller dans cette voie mène directement au même genre d'incohérences (*cure-ongles* mais *cure-dent*, *garde-meuble* variable ou non...) qu'on a tenté d'éliminer en 1990. *Antipersonnel* s'accorde au scrabble, mais l'ODS est compilé de plusieurs dictionnaires et je ne sais pas d'où cela a été tiré.

Answer (score -2):

Je crois que l'expression "mines antipersonnel" est un néologisme traduisant l'expression anglaise "antipersonal landmines". Le caractère invariable de "antipersonnel" en français résulte, à mon avis, du caractère invariable de l'adjectif anglais "antipersonal".

L'usage veut que "antipersonnel" soit invariable, même si c'est grammaticalement illogique en français.

Ainsi, la Convention d'Oslo/Ottawa du 18 septembre 1997 interdit l'emploi, le stockage, la production et le transfert "des mines antipersonnel" et exige leur destruction. Dans ce texte, "antipersonnel" est utilisé de manière invariable : nouvel exemple du Fachoda linguistique du français...

Comment: Fachoda... Tu parles de [ça](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crise_de_Fachoda) ? Pardon mais si oui je n'ai pas saisi le rapport dans le contexte...

Comment: C'est drôle, parce q'en anglais, les mines antipersonel, ce sont des *anti-personnel mines* (pas *antipersonal*), ce qui reflète encore mieux le sens du nom. C'est pas une attaque personnelle...